# memcpy causes strange Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I get a Segmentation fault although my C program seems to be PERFECT!
Here is how it works:

> Assuming that we have a struct Heap containing 6 ints and 1 int*.
>   (the size is 32 bytes)

```
struct Heap
{
  int* a;
  int  b;
  int  c;
  int  d; 
  int  e;
  bool f; // Trust me it's int
  bool g; // Trust me it's int
};
```

> In the **main()** i call:

```
examine(heap, enable_cloning);
```

> what **examine()** does is:

```
...
    if(!enable_cloning)
    {
        Heap* my_clone = new_Heap_from_clone(heap); // A clone is being made ...
...
```

> Now let's jump to the tricky part (inside **new_Heap_from_clone()**)

```
Heap* new_Heap_from_clone(Heap const* the_original_or_clone_heap)
{
    Heap* heap = malloc(sizeof(Heap));
    if(heap == NULL)
        return NULL;

    memcpy(heap, the_original_or_clone_heap, sizeof(Heap)); //Happy Segmentation Fault !!!
    ...
```

> Running GDB i get:

```
(gdb) step
174     memcpy(heap, the_original_or_clone_heap, sizeof(the_original_or_clone_heap));
(gdb) step

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554dae in new_Heap_from_clone (the_original_or_clone_heap=0xb) at ./Heap.c:174
174     memcpy(heap, the_original_or_clone_heap, sizeof(the_original_or_clone_heap));
(gdb) sizeof *heap
Undefined command: "sizeof".  Try "help".
(gdb) print sizeof *heap
$5 = 32
(gdb) print sizeof *the_original_or_clone_heap
$6 = 32
```

> ***Note:***  *that i included the sizes of what **memcpy()** gets so that i get more precious info from you!*
>   Let's see what valgrind has to say about that:

```
==6244== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==6244==    at 0x108DAE: new_Heap_from_clone (Heap.c:174)
==6244==    by 0x1095ED: heapSort (Heap.c:481)
==6244==    by 0x10915F: sort (Heap.c:330)
==6244==    by 0x10A897: ds_bench (main.c:90)
==6244==    by 0x10A9B4: main (main.c:106)
==6244== 
==6244== Invalid read of size 8
==6244==    at 0x108DAE: new_Heap_from_clone (Heap.c:174)
==6244==    by 0x1095ED: heapSort (Heap.c:481)
==6244==    by 0x10915F: sort (Heap.c:330)
==6244==    by 0x10A897: ds_bench (main.c:90)
==6244==    by 0x10A9B4: main (main.c:106)
==6244==  Address 0xb is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6244== 
==6244== 
==6244== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6244==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xB
==6244==    at 0x108DAE: new_Heap_from_clone (Heap.c:174)
==6244==    by 0x1095ED: heapSort (Heap.c:481)
==6244==    by 0x10915F: sort (Heap.c:330)
==6244==    by 0x10A897: ds_bench (main.c:90)
==6244==    by 0x10A9B4: main (main.c:106)
==6244==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6244==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6244==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6244==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6244==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 12001280.
==6244== 
==6244== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6244==     in use at exit: 1,648 bytes in 31 blocks
==6244==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 1 frees, 2,672 bytes allocated
==6244== 
==6244== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6244==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6244==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6244==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6244==    still reachable: 1,648 bytes in 31 blocks
==6244==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6244== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==6244== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==6244== 
==6244== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6244== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6244== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Keep in mind that i have no previous experience with valgrind but it says the obvious:

> ==6244==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xB

BUT I don't think that there is such a problem... 
Is the any possibility of running (somehow) out of stack space?
BUT EVEN in such a case a run valgrind with:

> valgrind --leak-check=yes `--main-stacksize=12000000` ./hxn
>   that is more than its default (8388608) and got the same answer as you see.

So WHAT ON EARTH SEEMS TO BE THE POINT?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't help otherwise.

Comment: Where does the `heap` in `main()` point to and how is this pointed to memory defined (and initialised)?

Comment: "*if (!enable_cloning) ...// A clone is being made ...*" hmm?

Comment: Please post *actual* code not something cobbled together. I can see it's not your real code because your arguments are `Heap`, yet you have no `typedef` only `struct Heap`.

Comment: You say `if(!enable_cloning)`, but then you comment on the body of this if-statement says `// A clone is being made`. Are you sure this is how it's supposed to be? Moreover, please provide more information, as requested by the other users. For example, there is no `Heap` here.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The OP seems to use a C++ compiler, but well ...

Comment: My bet goes on `the_original_or_clone_heap` containing garbage and with this pointing to garbage ...

Comment: Note the cloning function does not clone the content that the struct member `*a` is pointing to, only the control structure, and they will share their data. Later if you `free` one of them (and its content), the other will fail.

Comment: @Weather Vane look how experienced  programmers (John Perry ) understand experience one's questions and post possible solutions a..Don't try to struggle hard by playing with the words..

Answer (score 4):

You're passing an uninitialized pointer to `new_Heap_from_clone()`. Both gdb and valgrind are trying to tell you that:

- gdb is telling you the pointer is `0xb`, which is a classical value of an uninitialized pointer in gdb; and
- valgrind can't get any more obvious when it says, `Use of uninitialised value of size 8`.

This gets through the check because `0xb` is not null; `0x0` is. So, when you call `new_Heap_from_clone(heap)` you must not have initialized that particular `heap` with the value `null` when you should have.

Use gdb's backtracking abilities (`up` to go up in the call stack, `down` to go down) to figure out exactly where this goes wrong.

Comment: SORRY FOR REPOSTING BUT THE Stackoverflow sucks with commenting code:
You seem to be my man! (Y) The heap that i passed to `examine(heap, enable_cloning);` has already been initialized in main() by calling the "constructor" `Heap* new_Heap_from_data(bool buildMaxHeap, int* data, int size)`. This function does the appropriate initialization required. AND IT IS THOROGHLY TESTED CODE!

Comment: There's no way you could initialize a pointer at `0xb`. The pointer you're passing in has not been initialized. Backtracking in gdb should tell you precisely where, but: try, for instance, `examine(&heap, enable_cloning)` instead of `examine(heap, enable_cloning)` (notice the ampersand) -- unless `heap` is already a pointer to `Heap`, in which case the problem is probably not something we can diagnose with the information given: you'll have to backtrack in gdb or something similar.

Comment: ALL vars are ponters! :) Haha ..that's why i tell you I CANNOT find a solution. Valgrind has also mentioned a 0x2A also (before i decide to post the question)
`Access not within mapped region at address 0x2A` Do you know what this value "meaning"? Thanks for your precious advices beforehand!

Comment: @javase As long as you refuse to post a [mcve], you're just going to get guesses.

Comment: @javase you have been on this site for 5 years so please stop expressing your contempt for the site and for volunteers offering help and read the tour, which you have not yet done.

Comment: @javase `0x2A` is also an indication of an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @John Perry So i will give my best to prove that gdb and valgrid are right! I've no doubt about that though. But assuming that my code has suffered a Heisenbug :P (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) due to race conditions (possibly) I'll give my best. :) (it is all about a high performance code - and i think that might explain these situations i experience) 
Thank you A   L O T!

Comment: @javase Are you doing parallel programming?

Comment: Homogeneous yes not Hetergeneous. But this has to do with data structures that i'm optimizing.